# sort a array of arrays based on array length and array value (date format) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a scenario where I have an array of arrays containing object and I need to sort the array where internal arrays of length 1 are displayed at the top and internal arrays length greater than one are sorted based on values inside the object.

```js
let a = [[{c:"11-01-2020"}], [{c:"12-01-2020"}, {c:"12-01-2020"}], [{c:"13-01-2020"}, {c:"13-01-2020"}], [{c:"14-01-2020"}]]

function sortfn(a, b) {
  if (a.length === 1 && b.length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a.length === 1 ||
    (a[0].c > b[0].c) &&
    a.length !== 1 &&
    b.length !== 1
  ) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}

a.sort(sortfn);

console.log(a)
```

result should be

```
[[{c:"11-01-2020"}], [{c:"14-01-2020"}]], [{c:"13-01-2020"}, {c:"13-01-2020"}], [{c:"12-01-2020"}, {c:"12-01-2020"}]]
```

Comment: Will all the objects in an subarray will have equal value of `c`

Comment: are arrays of length 1 sorted on anything between themselves?

Comment: yes all the sub arrays will have the value c

Comment: arrays of length 1 are not sorted between themselves and not required but it should be placed at the top

Comment: Your code gives error when I made a snippet - you need to define `firstObject`

Comment: firstObject works only in ember you can use some other approach to get the value of first object in the array. I have mentioned it in the question P.S

Comment: Feel free to delete the post if there is no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for length first and then sort by date strings.

```js
const
    getISODate = custom => custom.replace(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/, '$3-$2-$1'),
    sortFn = (a, b) => (b.length === 1) - (a.length === 1) || getISODate(a[0].c).localeCompare(getISODate(b[0].c)),
    array = [[{ c: "11-01-2020" }], [{ c: "12-01-2020" }, { c: "12-01-2020" }], [{ c: "13-01-2020" }, { c: "13-01-2020" }], [{ c: "14-01-2020" }]]

array.sort(sortFn);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you edit the solution for the edited question??

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work for you?

```js
let a = [[{c:2}], [{c:4}, {c:4}], [{c:3}, {c:3}], [{c:1}]]

a.sort((a,b) => a[0].c - b[0].c);

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above post to sort using date and it worked

Thank You

```js
function sortfn(a, b) {
    return (b.length === 1) - (a.length === 1) || new Date(b[0].c) - new Date(a[0].c);
}

let a = [[{ c: "11-11-2020" }], [{ c: "12-11-2020"  }, { c: "12-11-2020"  }], [{ c: "13-11-2020"  }, { c: "13-11-2020"  }], [{ c :"14-11-2020"  }]];

a.sort(sortfn);

console.log(a);
```